# Change inline JS to click function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to clean up some code. I have a button that has the following inline JS

```
<input id="lookup" type="submit" name="lookup" value="Search" onclick="changestart('1')" />
```

I would like to change the onclick to a jQuery click funnction but am getting no success. Here is the "changestart" function

```
function changestart(direction) {
    var rowsElement  = $("#maxrows");
    var rowsValue    = parseInt(rowsElement.val());
    var startElement = $("#startID");
    var value        = parseInt(startElement.val());
    startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ? value - rowsValue : 1);
}

$("#previous").click(function(){changestart('back');});
$("#next").click(function(){changestart('forward');});
```

I've tried

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart.val(1);});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to accomplish with the button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code defaults down to `1` anyway, you can just do this:

```
$("#lookup").click(changestart);
```

There's no [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method on functions, and the argument you're passing doesn't matter anyway, anything *except* `"forward"` and `"back"` are `1`, so you can pass with no argument as well, which is what the above code does.

Comment: so the other answers also work, but yours is even shorter. Awesome. Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just mean:

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart(1);});
```

Comment: and @JamesStuddart - thanks guys, this works. I did not know that when setting value for a function you don't need .val(). I have a lot to learn, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){ changestart(1); });
```

Comment: thank you. so when you are setting a value for a function you do not use .val? Learned something, thank you sir!

Comment: Nope.  val() is used for getting/setting the value of a form element.  For example, $('form select').val() would provide the value of the option that the select element is currently set to.  Similarly, $('form select').val(5) would set it to the option with a value of 5.  Also works with other form elements like checkboxes, radio buttons, input fields & textfields (did I leave any out?).  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the javascript is either under the button in the markup OR use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lookup").click(function(){changestart(1);});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<input id="lookup" type="submit" name="lookup" value="Search" onclick="changestart('1')" />
```

to

```
<input id="lookup" type="submit" name="lookup" value="Search"/>
```

and

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart.val(1);});
```

to

```
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart(1);});
```